# Creating a GET request for a JSON to KDB table?

Tags: json, http, kdb

I'm looking to visualize some data with KX Dashboard. Data should be update regularly by means of polling. I have manually tested the polling and connection to my KDB server instance and it works.

However, I am unable to create a suitable GET request for a JSON file which then can be inserted to a table that will be shown visually in KX Dashboard.

I am following the guide by Timestored here: http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/kdb-http-webserver

**Query issued:**

```
q) httpGet:{[host;location] (`$":http://",host)"GET ",location," HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:",host,"\r\n\r\n"};
q) b: httpGet[ "www.google.com"; "/"]
```

**Timeout error:**

```
conn. OS reports: Connection timed out
  [16] httpGet:{[host;location] (`$":http://",host)"GET ",location," HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:",host,"\r\n\r\n"}
```

I would appreciate a sample on how I can create a proper GET request and retrieve a JSON i.e. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ , and parse it into an existing table for visualization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have included below a code snippet which will grab and parse JSON from the link you provided.

```
q).j.k .Q.hg`:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
userId   | 1f
id       | 1f
title    | "delectus aut autem"
completed| 0b
```

This code uses .Q.hg which takes a URL as an argument, runs a Get query, and returns the response as a string. .j.k then takes this string then converts it into a K object.

Also the timestored article you linked was published before .Q.hg was added the the Dot Q Namespace. .Q.hg allows you to run HTTP requests more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works perfectly. I have a proxy question, is there an additional port that funnels this request for KDB? The command works fine on my local machine, but on my work machine it doesn't go through. I am certain a firewall is blocking the request, but I am uncertain which port KDB utilises.

Comment: .Q.hg automatically uses a proxy if one is define in your `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable. I would begin by checking your environment variables. Also if you want to read into it you can look at the documentation here: https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/dotq/#qhg-http-get

Comment: @Jonathan I'm able to run this for my stem but if I add a query string, I get a "type" error. Is there a proper way to encode my query string parameters?